# Reference types Explicit Conversion in c#

Tags: c#

As I'm new to C#, So trying to explore the things. I came up with an ambiguity here,

As per MSDN:- An explicit cast is required if you need to convert from a base type to a derived type for Reference Types

Here's [the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).
So i tried an example program

```
interface I1
    {
        void FirstInterface();
    }
    class A 
    {
        public void FirstInterface()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FirstInterface Implemented in Class A");
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        public void ClassBMethods()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class B methods");
        }
    }

Void Main()
{
   A baseClass = new A();
   B derivedClass = (B)baseClass;   //Converting from base type to derived type
 //B derivedClass = baseClass as B;  ->  null
}
```

But I'm getting `Invalid Cast Exception` when trying to do an explicit cast.Can anyone help me out to make this understand. I'm not sure what i misunderstood here.

Comment: The MSDN example starts with a Giraffe, converts it to Animal, then casts it back to Giraffe. This works because the "underlying type" is still a Giraffe even though "the value being used as a reference to the (Giraffe) object" is of type Animal. In your example the "underlying type" is A, so it's not able to be cast to the more derived type of B.

Answer (score 1):

The `baseClass` instance is not of type `B`. It is of type `A`. No amount of casting will make it a type `B`.

Try the following.

```
A baseClass = new B();
B derivedClass = (B)baseClass;
B otherDerivedClass = baseClass as B;
```

Notice the **A baseClass = new B();**

So think about it this way, a circle is always a shape, but a shape is not always a circle. With that in mind, the following makes sense:

```
Shape shape = new Circle();
Circle circle = (Circle)shape;
```

While the following does not:

```
Shape shape = new Shape();
Circle circle = (Circle)shape;
```

In the former, the shape was instantiated *as a circle*, so you can cast back and forth. In the latter, the shape was not ever a circle, so you can't cast to a circle.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `baseClass` isn't of type `B`.  Explicit casting would be more for something  like this

```
A baseReference = new B();
B derivedReference = (B)baseReference;
```

Or to be safe you and use `as` instead which will return the default (`null` in the case of reference types) if the cast fails.

```
A a = new A();
A aRefOfB = new B();
B aAsB = a as B;
B aRefOfBAsB = aRefOfB as B;
```

In that case `aAsB` will be `null` and `aRefOfBAsB` will not.

But in general you should prefer a design that doesn't require you to do any explicit casts in the first place if possible.